# How can I deal with broken contraints when unit testing in Django?

Tags: python, django

Consider these two Django models:

```
MyModelA(models.Model):
    my_foreign_key = models.ForeignKey('MyModelB')

MyModelB(models.Model):
    some_stuff = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

The models correctly represent how the data should be. The problem is that some MyModelA records have foreign keys to MyModelB's that don't exist.  (I'm using MySQL.)

I cannot fix the broken data, so I'm writing my code to handle the bad data gracefully.

My problem is I now want to test the code, but I cannot create a foreign key to an object that doesn't exist, the Django ORM wont let me.

How can I violate the Django ORM constraints in order to create a unit test?

Comment: Have you tried `m = MyModelA()`, `m.my_foreign_key_id = n`, `m.save()`, where `n` is a non-existent id? That should work and return `X matching query does not exist` if you try to access the foreign key.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Yes, give your comment as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the foreign key id directly and then save the model:

```
m = MyModelA()
m.my_foreign_key_id = n
m.save()
```

where `n` is a non-existent id. That will fail with `matching query does not exist` if you try to access the foreign key.